# Sentence with 'remain as '

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I am a bit confused about which of the following two sentences are correct (if any). I searched online but could not find any good example. I will be grateful if you can help me on this.

1. In addition, the continuation of low price environment in 2017 means that cost reduction will remain as one of the key priorities for the industry.
2. In addition, the continuation of low price environment in 2017 means that cost reduction will remain to be one of the key priorities for the industry.

Also, should I use would instead of will in the above examples?

Comment: It would seem to me that something can *remain as*, but I don't see how it can *remain to be*. Usage of *...to be* suggests a change is to take place, so *remain* is not appropriate. I would also suggest that it should be *low-priced environment* or *a low price environment*.

Comment: Option 1 is fine, but I would drop *as*. It's unnecessary. Option 2 with *remain to be* is not right.

Comment: @WS2 But something can ***continue to be*** something.

Comment: @Scott Good point. I suppose this is, at the end of the day, all about idiomacy. I can say 'It remains *to be* seen if she will win'.  But I am less confident with 'It remains *to be* a key priority'. Though 'It continues *to be* a key priority' is fine. The difference here is the nature of the verb 'remain', which as Richard Kayser has pointed out would stand on its own, without a following preposition. It is more difficult in this example to make 'continue' do that. Though one can say 'The weather continues fine'. Ahh! English and its idioms!

Answer (score 2):

option 1 is correct, regarding both of your questions.

a) If you wanted to say "will `<something`> to be" you'd say "continue" rather than "remain".  In other words, you can say *"will remain as one of the..."* **or** *"will continue to be one of the"*, but don't mix them up.  These two alternatives mean the same thing in this context and both are commonly used.

b) Saying "would" instead of "will" makes it **hypothetical** which isn't what you want to do: you're making a prediction about the real situation, not a hypothetical one.

You'd use "would" in a situation like "If there is a large change to interest rates in 2017 then cost reduction **would** continue to be...".  Here you're talking about a hypothetical situation (interest rates increasing) AND you're implying that if that situation doesn't come about then cost reduction **might not** remain as one of the key priorities.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think anyone will say that the following sentence doesn't work:

> It remains to be seen.

This shows that "remain to be" is just fine.

In fact I like your second sentence better than your first.

I found another example at http://www.macmillandictionary.com/us/dictionary/american/remain

> It (only) remains for me to do something.

Comment: In "it remains to be seen", it's referring to a future action: something that hasn't happened yet. In "remain to be one of the key priorities for the industry" you're not referring to a future action, but a present state that will continue.